# Import y Export JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-import

Tengo un pequeño proyecto de un juego en JS que se basa en combate por turnos contra una IA que estoy programando.

Ahora, necesito traer de un archivo que se llama "clases.js" justamente las clases como mi IA y mi jugador, cada uno con sus estadísticas principales.

```
export class humano {       
  constructor() {
    this.hp = 500
    this.hpv = this.hp
    this.atk = 13   }

  atacar(who){
    who.hpv=who.hpv - this.atk  } };
```

Ahora a ese class quiero llamarlo de mi 'index.js' que es el archivo principal donde hago todas las acciones.

```
import humano from 'clases.js';
let jorge = new humano;
console.log(jorge);
```

Quiero creer que es asi el como se importa una clase o lo que fuere de otro archivo no?.

El error que me da la consola de Chrome es:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Espero puedan darme una manito, la idea con este proyecto es poder aprender Javascript mejor, soy relativamente nuevo en lo que es programación pero de apoco practicando a diario voy sintiendo mas soltura, pero si no pregunto no avanzo :) muchas gracias y espero halla formulado bien la pregunta.

Edito!!
Talvez deba usar Babel... no lo entiendo bien.. ustedes diran.

Comment: Lo que se ve a simple vista son puros errores de sintáxis, ¿estás trabajando javascript puro o typescript?

Comment: Sinceramente creo que javascript.. no sabria decirte. Por que caso lo decis? es por la falta de alguna ; ? ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas agregar default, export default class Human si usas es2016

o simplemente:

```
class Human {

}

module.exports = Human;

// or
export default Human;
```

esto es por que puedes exportar de diferentes formas

```
// Export
var obj = {};
var myVariable = 0;
module.exports.obj = obj;
module.exports.myVariable = myVariable;

export const obj = {};
export const myVariable = {};

// import
const { obj, myVariable } = require('./human');
const { obj, myVariable } from './human';
```

no necesitas agregar la extension .js,  hay una jerarquia de busqueda de archivos donde busca primero la extension .js despues .json

Nota:
Si vas a utilizar clases ocupas usar babel, chrome ya soporta varios features de es6 pero las clases todavia no, y otra cosas JavaScript Destructuring assignment => import {} from; eso aun no ha llegado ni a la version 7 de node, es un feature que va a tardar un tiempo en llegar tal vez el proximo anio, asi que te recomiendo que uses babel si quieres trabajar con estos features, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias armando!! .. ahora estoy camino a mi trabajo de mortal, apenas llegue a casa lo reviso, pero voy a estudiar bien tu respuesta asi mas tarde concluyo el tema..

Comment: Me resulta raro lo q dijieron de mala sintaxis. Si el navegador me lo toma no se porque dice lo de sintaxis mala.. vos le ves algo malo? Mas q nada para mejorar..

Comment: No miro nada raro en la sintaxis solo que no agregaste 'export default' te dejo un enlace a uno repo de prueba donde use babel, te puede servir de referencia https://github.com/armandomendivil/k-nearest-neighbor

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, recien abro el stack desde hace unos dias.. tal cual decias era eso, solo que toca ocupar babel! .. muy amable armando.